# Python web scrape - not displaying all containers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

`page_soup.findall` won't seem to get all containers. when running len(containers) it shows I have 12 containers but its only pulling info from one. can someone plz help. I'm trying to get info for all 12 containers.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20card'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

for container in containers:
    brand = container.img["title"]

    title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text 

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

print ("brand: " + brand)
print ("product_name: " + product_name)
print ("shipping : " + shipping)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks good and it is getting all 12 containers, but you are printing only last one.
in order to print all, use last three print lines inside for loop. like this

```
for container in containers:
     brand = container.img["title"]
     title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class": "item-title"})
     product_name = title_container[0].text
     shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class": "price-ship"})
     shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()
     print("brand: " + brand)
     print("product_name: " + product_name)
     print("shipping : " + shipping)
```